# ASP.NET application/web service not working on Windows Vista/IIS 7: access right problem?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, service

I have a .NET 3.5 based web service running at http://localhost/serivce.svc/. Then I have an ASP.NET application running at http://localhost/myApp. In `Application_Load` my application reads some XML configuration from the web service. That works fine on my machine, but:

- On Windows Vista with IIS 7 the request to the web services fails.
- The web service can be accessed via the browser without any problem.
- I configured the app pool of my application to run as admin. I added the admin to the IIS_USRS group, but it still cannot access the web service. `impersonate=true/false` seems not to make a difference.

Comment: "request to the webervices fails" - how does it fail? Is there an exception? Please post it. Is there anything in the event logs? Post that.

Comment: I get a 503 from the webservice back. I wrote the accessed url to a log file and it works fine in the browser. As the code works fine if started from Visual Studio, I was not yet able to get more information via the debugger.

Comment: I tried to debug the problem further. If I configure myApp with a bad URL which does not exist, I still get an 503. This is strange, because I would expect a 404. I tried to use Fiddler to have a look at the details of the request, but no request shows up in Fiddler. So I assume that the request does not even leaves myApp. Somehow local request must be forbidden on that machine, but I don't know why and how to check that!?

Comment: fiddler will not show sessions to localhost - the IE proxy bits are hard coded to not use proxies for localhost, instead use http://127.0.0.1./example (that extra . is meant to be there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, take admin out of the IIS_WPG group before you forget, and configure your app pool back to normal.

Now, turn on WCF logging on the service by putting the following in your web.config file -

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
                <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="c:\logs\web_messages.svclog"*
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
            <filter type="" />
        </add>
    </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>


<system.serviceModel>
...
   <diagnostics>
     <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" *logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"*
       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
   </diagnostics>
...
</system.ServiceModel>
```

Create the c:\logs directory and make sure the application pool identity user has full control on that directory. Now test your app.

If no log files are being created then there's a problem reaching the WCF service.
If log files are being created view them in the Service Trace viewer which comes as part of the Windows SDK. You'll see a red message which is the log entry containing the exception thrown inside the service - this should give you a pointer to where your service code is going wrong.

If the problem is inside your app, rather than the service then you should be logging exceptions inside your `Application_Load` event (you should be logging exceptions anyway) - however if you try with a global exception handler, well, your app is failing on startup and so the global exception handler will never start to run - instead of putting potential failable scenarios in `Application_Load` I'd move that out to a utility class which provides an access point to the information you need (say myGlobalThingumy.GetStuff()). Make this class a singleton, and then check if you have the stuff already - if you don't, then you make your web service call. It would act much the same as putting it in `Application_Load` but will enable global error handling to work, and make your debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give access to the IIS_USRS group on the folder that contains the web service, and check again :).

Comment: That's not the problem. Every part of the system works in isolation, if I change configuration to access data from a different machine. The problem only comes up if both instances are running on vista.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the 503 errors, have you considered looking at the event viewer on the machine to see if IIS logged the exception.

When started from Visual Studio, is it running in the Visual Studio web server or IIS? (This is a critical point. Visual Studio, since 2005, has used its own web server by default for web projects. And this web server is executed under your user account -- also critical for what's coming next.)

You're attempting to read some XML goodness out of a file. In .NET, in order to read a file, for some reason the user executing the code (in IIS7 I believe it is IIS_USERS and NETWORK SERVICE; in older versions of IIS, IUSR_MachineName and ASPNET) have to have both read and *write* access permissions. So the very first thing I'd check is the ACL on that XML file. Make sure the appropriate users have read/write access. This would be the NTFS permissions, by the way -- right-click the file in Explorer, choose Security, and add the appropriate perms.

What gave it away is that it works when you run the solution from Visual Studio, but not when it's executed from IIS. I don't believe you're getting 503 back from the web service -- you're most likely getting 503 from `myApp` itself.

The reason for this 503 is because you're attempting to read this file on `Application_Load`. That means that before any page can even attempt to be served, your XML file must be read and parsed. Upon reflection, and re-reading the question one more time, I'm now 99.99% certain that the inability to read this file (due to the lack of write permissions on it) is the issue.

My advice: Take out all of the admin stuff you'd done, take your user/ACL configuration back to normal, how it was -- including the AppPool. Then, follow the advice above to grant the appropriate IIS users read/write access to the XML file. I'm 99.99% sure your app will now work in IIS.

Comment: Your explanation sounds logical to me, but I think there is one misunderstanding: The XML configuration is not read from the file system. It's read via HTTP from a URL with is located on the same server (http://localhost/serivce.svc/). My process might not be allowed to access that URL, but how to check that?

Comment: I'm not certain why that would be off the top of my head; however I'm still fairly convinced your 503s are due to `Application_Load`. At this point, I'd probably have to see more of the app ... At this point, if you're using WCF, it's time to start using blowdart's advice.